# Can you completely determine a finitely presented finite group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G = \langle S \mid R \rangle$ be a finitely presented group. Suppose you know $G$ is finite. Can you completely construct the group multiplication table?

I feel like the answer is yes. My first thought is to construct homomorphisms into symmetric groups, but I am not quite sure how to go about it.

Comment: See also "word problem" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups

Comment: As far as I know , this problem is undecidable.

Comment: @GEdgar Actually, since everything is constrained to be finite, this is decidable. See my answer.

Comment: @Peter Actually, since everything is constrained to be finite, this is decidable. See my answer.

Comment: Todd-Coxeter coset enumeration effectively achieves this. It calculates the action of the group generators in the regular permutation representation, which determines the complete multiplication table.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In fact, in this case you *can* determine the group! Finiteness is absolutely crucial here, however.

Let's say our generators are $a_1,...,a_n$, our relators are $R_1,...,R_m$, and every element of our group is represented by a word of length $\le l$. Then any word of length $l+1$ can be transformed into a word of length $\le l$ by applying an appropriate (perhaps extremely long) sequence of relations. Once we see this phenomenon we know we've found all the elements of the group. Since for any $l$ there are only finitely many words of length $l+1$, via appropriate brute-force search we can eventually find and recognize such an $l$ if it exists, so there's no need for us to be given an upper bound on the lengths of the words at the outset. (Of course the first such $l$ we find might not be the *smallest* such $l$, since by using longer sequences of relations it may turn out that a shorter value of $l$ would have sufficed, but that's fine.)

- EDIT: Here's a bit more detail on the brute-force detection of $l$. Say that a pair of numbers $(l,m)$ is **stable** iff every word of length $l+1$ can be converted to a word of length $\le l$ by applying a sequence of relations of length at most $m$. Since there are only finitely many generators and relations, we can check whether $(l,m)$ is stable in finite time. Now just cycle through all possible pairs of numbers as follows: $$(1,1), (1,2), (2,2), (1,3), (2,3), (3,3),..., (1,n),...,(n,n),...$$ (this is a trick called *dovetailing*). As long as the group is in fact finite a stable pair must exist, and so our search will eventually halt. Now note that the first stable pair we run into may have first coordinate much larger than optimal; e.g. maybe $(10,100)$ is stable but so is $(9,1000)$. That's fine! This process isn't guaranteed to find the smallest such $l$, just *some* working $l$.

Once we have found such a sufficiently large $l$, we can just try to greedily build the  multiplication table (my original idea with graphs did not work, as pointed out by Eric Wofsey and Adayah below). At any given stage, we'll have a guess at an equivalence relation on the set $L$ of words of length $\le 2l$. At each stage we check whether the multiplication/inverse tables this equivalence relation generates on the set of words of length $\le l$ (we need to go up to length $2l$ to deal with multiplications) satisfies the group axioms and our relations; if it doesn't, then we add the appropriate pairs to our equivalence relation and rinse-and-repeat. Eventually we wind up with the smallest equivalence relation which satisfies our constraints, which gives our group.

Note that nothing here relies on groups per se; the same basic idea would work for any sort of algebraic structure.

Comment: Interesting! I guess that we still need a bit of extra information, namely, an effective upper bound for lengths of words? (Of course, I'm jittery about the word problem...) :)

Comment: @paulgarrett Nope! We can find an upper bound on the lengths of the words just by doing brute force search (appropriately dovetailed). If there is some $l$ such that every word of length $l+1$ is equivalent to some word of length $\le l$, we'll eventually find such an $l$. Of course, the *first* such $l$ we find might not be the *smallest*, but that's okay.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Very interesting! :)

Comment: I think I am starting to get it now. So once you see the words of length $l+1$
 can be made into words of length $l$, you can repeatedly apply this to subwords of longer words. I am wondering if you could end up going in circles applying relations to words to see if they get shorter. I assume that because there are only finitely many letters and relations that there must be finitely many words under a certain length and these can all be known?

Comment: Quick check to make sure I'm thinking about this right: this works, but there are no  elementary bounds on $l$ in terms of $m$ and $n$, correct? (Since if there were a computable bound on $l$ we could use it to solve the unconstrained version of the question)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Indeed, that's right. The issue is that the function sending the group-presentation data to the relevant $l$ is only a **partial** computable function: if we feed it data which happens to not describe a finite group, it will never halt. The set of finite presentations of finite groups is c.e. but not co-c.e., so we can never avoid the "bad inputs."

Comment: I don't follow the final paragraph.  How exactly do you get a graph whose edges are the applications of the relations?  If you start with a word $w_0$, you can cancel a relation or insert a relation anywhere in the middle.  But inserting a relation might result in a word $w_1$ of length longer than $l$.  You know one way to reduce $w_1$ down to a word $w_1'$ of length at most $l$, and so you draw an edge between $w_0$ and $w_1'$.  But what if you instead then insert another relation into $w_1$ to get a longer word $w_2$?  The reduced version of $w_2$ might be different from $w_1'$.

Comment: You could keep inserting more and more relations before reducing down to a word of length at most $l$, so how do you know when you've actually found all the edges in your graph?

Comment: I guess one thing you could do instead is just build the multiplication table of your group.  Start with the full list of words of length at most $l$ and write out the multiplication (and inverse) table.  If it does not satisfy the group axioms as well as all of your relations, pick a pair of elements you need to identify in order for the axioms and relations to be satisfied.  Now build the multiplication table again with these two elements identified.  Repeat until you reach a multiplication table that satisfies the axioms and relations.

Comment: I don't understand the last part of the procedure: suppose you end up with a graph with two components that looks like $\mathbb{Z}_2$. How can you tell if $G = \mathbb{Z}_2$ or $G = \{ e \}$? The two elements that appear distinct might be equal, but knowing this could require a very long sequence of transformations (going through words of length way beyond $l$).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Would you be able to provide some more detail on how you would contruct the brute-force search to recognize such an $l$?

Comment: @cede See my edit.

Comment: @EricWofsey You're right, I was being sloppy. Fixing ...

Comment: @Adayah You (and Eric above) are right, I was being sloppy. Eric's trick with the multiplication table is the right way to go.

Comment: @cede That said, Eric and Adayah pointed out an error in my graph approach. I've replaced that with Eric's idea which actually works.

Comment: Thank you for the effort to address my question, but I feel it hasn't been properly answered (neither by yourself, nor by Eric). Imagine that your final "guess" for the equivalence relation has two classes. The multiplication table, inverses and everything else that the algorithm can verify up to the length $\leqslant 2l$ indicates that $G = \mathbb{Z}_2$. How do you guarantee that $G \neq \{ e \}$ in a finite time?